# What should we do about stained hardwood floors that are still wet after three days?

Tags: hardwood-floor, staining

My husband and I made the mistake of applying too much stain to our freshly sanded hardwood floors.  After learning this mistake we wiped them with extra stain and wiped them off immediately. This helped remove much of the tackiness. However they still felt sticky after 48 hours so we scrubbed them with mineral spirits which seemed to help a little more. Twelve hours later they still feel slightly oily.  I feel like we have done everything at this point.

How much longer do we wait?  How do we know they are actually dry?  Besides resanding, what else can we do?

Comment: Was it stain or a stain/polyurethane combination?

Comment: What do the directions on the container say? You may just have to wait it out and increase ventilation to the room.

Comment: If it is just stain (bib asks a good question) you can tie rags to your shoes and slide around the floor.  This (the added weight) helps pull some of the excess stain off the top.  Fan pointing into the room, directly on the floor (but don't do that for finish...dust is bad) and if it is humid the AC will also help it dry.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen in 2007. I put too much stain(MinWax) on the floors and the air conditioning went out in the house so it was too moist for it to dry. I wiped it all down but found it too dark in spots. We ended up resanding and starting from scratch. I would try wiping it down and if not too dark, good. I would also turn up the air conditioning if you have it. It was very important here in the south to manage humidity as it turns out. Michael